# Python 3 Validation loop restarting with definition

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a simple menu where a user inputs either a monster choice or the word quite. I want the program to loop back if the wrong input was received. 
When i enter the first wrong answer i do get the prompt to re enter but it does not then print out the statement. So its not looping correct.

```
def welcomeScreen():
    print("Welcome to the Creature computation tool!\n\n")
    menu = str("MENU")
    print(menu.center(40, '*'))

def monsterMenu(monster): 

    print("{0} - Compute probability of {0}".format(monster))

def quitMenu():
    endMenu = str("Quit")
    print("{0} - Quit the tool".format(endMenu))

def chooseMontser():
    pickedMonster = input("Please Enter your choice of Monster: ")
    if pickedMonster == "Yeti":
        print ("You have picked", pickedMonster)
    elif pickedMonster == "Dragon":
        print ("You have picked", pickedMonster)
    elif pickedMonster == "Hydra":
        print ("You have picked", pickedMonster)
    elif pickedMonster == "Quit":
        print ("Thanks for using Creature Menu!")
    else:
        print("Please choose a valid option")
        chooseMonster()

def creatureMenu():
    welcomeScreen()
    monsterMenu("Yeti")
    monsterMenu("Dragon")
    monsterMenu("Hydra")
    quitMenu()
    chooseMontser()

creatureMenu()
```

Comment: I would suggest using a while loop instead of recursion. Also looks like there is a spelling mistake the func definition is chooseMontser() and the call inside the else condition is chooseMonster()

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have misspelt `chooseMonster` as `chooseMontser`. Here's another approach to your function:

```py
def chooseMonster():
    while True:
        pickedMonster = input("Please Enter your choice of Monster: ").lower()
        if pickedMonster == "yeti":
            break
        elif pickedMonster == "dragon":
            break
        elif pickedMonster == "hydra":
            break
        elif pickedMonster == "quit":
            print ("Thanks for using Creature Menu!")
            return
        else:
            print("Please choose a valid option")
    print ("You have picked", pickedMonster)
chooseMonster()
```

Using `.lower()` also allows the user's input to be case-insensitive as otherwise, your code would see 'dRAGon' as an incorrect input.